# Outputting the titles of the active folder

Tags: hugo, go-templates

I'm building a documentation site based on the Ace Documentation theme for Hugo.

The code I've pasted below is used by the site to generate the navigation menu on the left-hand side.

Using the template's [Getting Started](https://docs.vantage-design.com/ace/getting-started/) page as an example, what I want to do is only display the  title and content of the currently active folder (i.e. Getting Started > Installation, Usage); at the moment, it's displaying all folders.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light pl-0">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidenav-left-collapse" aria-controls="sidenav-left-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse align-items-start flex-column" id="sidenav-left-collapse">
        {{- if not .Site.Params.disableSearch}}
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 searchbox">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 w-100" data-search-input id="search-by" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            </form>
        {{- end}}
         <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column pt-3">
             {{- $currentNode := . }}
             {{- $showvisitedlinks := .Site.Params.showVisitedLinks -}}
             {{- if eq .Site.Params.ordersectionsby "title"}}
               {{- range .Site.Home.Sections.ByTitle}}
               {{- template "section-tree-nav" dict "sect" . "currentnode" $currentNode}}
               {{- end}}
             {{- else}}
               {{- range .Site.Home.Sections.ByWeight}}
               {{- template "section-tree-nav" dict "sect" . "currentnode" $currentNode}}
               {{- end}}
             {{- end}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Template -->
{{- define "section-tree-nav" }}
{{- $currentNode := .currentnode }}
{{- with .sect}}
{{- if and .IsSection (or (not .Params.hidden) $.showhidden)}}
    {{- $numberOfPages := (add (len .Pages) (len .Sections)) }}
    {{- safeHTML .Params.head}}
    <li data-nav-id="{{.RelPermalink}}" class="nav-item my-1
        {{- if .IsAncestor $currentNode}} parent{{end}}
        {{- if eq .RelPermalink $currentNode.RelPermalink}} active{{end}}
        {{- if .Params.alwaysopen}} alwaysopen{{end -}}
        {{- if ne $numberOfPages 0 }} haschildren{{end}}
        ">
        <!-- I'm the params head -->
        <a class="nav-link p-0" href="{{.RelPermalink}}"><h6>{{safeHTML .Params.Pre}}{{.Title}}{{safeHTML .Params.Post}}</h6></a>
      {{- if ne $numberOfPages 0 }}
        <ul class="list-unstyled ml-2">
          {{- .Scratch.Set "pages" .Pages }}
          {{- if .Sections}}
          {{- .Scratch.Set "pages" (.Pages | union .Sections) }}
          {{- end}}
          {{- $pages := (.Scratch.Get "pages") }}

        {{- if eq .Site.Params.ordersectionsby "title"}}
          {{- range $pages.ByTitle }}
            {{- if and .Params.hidden (not $.showhidden) }}
            {{- else}}
            {{- template "section-tree-nav" dict "sect" . "currentnode" $currentNode }}
            {{- end}}
          {{- end}}
        {{- else}}
          {{- range $pages.ByWeight }}
            {{- if and .Params.hidden (not $.showhidden) }}
            {{- else}}
            {{- template "section-tree-nav" dict "sect" . "currentnode" $currentNode }}
            {{- end}}
          {{- end}}
        {{- end}}
        </ul>
      {{- end}}
    </li>
{{- else}}
    {{- if not .Params.Hidden }}
        <li data-nav-id="{{.RelPermalink}}" class="nav-item my-1 {{- if eq .RelPermalink $currentNode.RelPermalink}} active{{end -}}">
                <!-- I'm the params hidden -->
                 <a href="{{.RelPermalink}}" class="nav-link p-0">
                    {{safeHTML .Params.Pre}}{{.LinkTitle}}{{safeHTML .Params.Post}}
                </a>
        </li>
    {{- end}}
{{- end}}
{{- end}}
{{- end}}
```